# magento 2 breadcrumbs on contact page

Tags: magento2, contact-us, breadcrumbs, magento-2.0.2

I am adding breadcrumb block on layout file `contact_index_index.xml` but not showing on contact page.

Following code for `contact_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I want to show breadcrumb on contactus page.

Comment: Check the module of @marius : https://github.com/tzyganu/m2-breadcrumbs

Comment: not working in 2.0.2

Comment: Refer http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/11/add-breadcrumbs-on-contact-page-magento.html, i got success.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thnks buddy...!!!

Comment: @Magev2. How can set home page URL/Link as Base URL?

Comment: @MikeSmith, when you use <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item> this will bring you to homepage if you don't use sub folder for your website url. If current, you are developing with sub folder, it will take you wrong link, but i think you will remove sub folder when you live site

Comment: @Magev2 got answer by using <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>

Comment: Perfect!! Thx you! In my case, my code must have translate="true" .

<action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string"  translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</item>
                </argument>
            </action>