# I want to change breadcrumbs First I want get page title then breadcrumbs

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to change my breadcrumbs in magento 2 but getting error with blank page. for example I am trying to do like this attachment.

```
   <?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
            <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) :?>
    <?php
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $title = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title');
    print_r($title);

    ?>
                <li class="item <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbName ?>">
                <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can do same thing in controller or layout xml file https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106295/magento-2-breadcrumbs-on-contact-page

Comment: have you got $title value?

Comment: Rakesh Jesadiya@I am not getting this $ $title value . Can  you help me regarding this

Comment: You can get title by echo $title->getShortHeading();

Comment: Ankit saha @this is only use for contact us page .I need all pages

Comment: Ankit saha@ any idea with XML file to change this

Comment: Ankit saha@ any idea with XML file to change this

Comment: S H Patel @$title->getShortHeading();  not working . any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do by adding below code above for loop in breadcrumbs.phtml file.

```
<?php $lastTitle = end($crumbs);?>
   <?php if(isset($lastTitle)):?>
        <span><strong><?php echo $lastTitle['label'];?></strong></span>
   <?php endif;?>
```

Full file code will be as follow:

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) :  ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <?php $lastTitle = end($crumbs);?>
    <?php if(isset($lastTitle)):?>
        <span><strong><?php echo $lastTitle['label'];?></strong></span>
    <?php endif;?>
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbName ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: For category pages title will not get because meta title is not added from backend, so it is better to use Label to display.

Comment: Brijal@ thanks for this , how can i follow you , Impressive

Comment: Brijal@ let me know how can I add link with this , code is workig and I am getting same that I want. but link is not working . any help

Comment: @SanjayYadav which link you are asking about? In above code it only shows last link label as a title. And there is no need to show link to that label because we are on that page only.

Comment: yes but when i click on  current page . then it's redirect me on home page

Answer (score 0):

Your page breaks because of your code

```
 $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title');
```

it should be create not get.
To get page title add below code in breadcrumb.php block file

```
public function getPageTitle()
{
    if (!empty($this->pageTitle)) {
        return $this->pageTitle;
    }
    return __($this->pageConfig->getTitle()->getShort());
}
```

Now call this function in phtml file

Comment: Brijal@ thanks for this  is Another good solution . Thanks for this